# PHP Root Domain of a website with failsafe

Tags: php

Is there a way to guarantee that one has the root domain of a website. Obviously one can do something like this:

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

But that is fine if the root domain is https://www.example.com. What if the root domain, is where the homepage of a particular website would be is actually a subdomain or worse, www.example.com/my-website/ as it is part of a larger network.

The situation has only arisen because of the use of MAMP where the root domain in local testing is invariably http://localhost888/my-web-site.

One idea was to lock onto the location of the htaccess file and determine the location from there. The only problem with this idea is that if someone has made a cock up an inadvertently put an htaccess file in the wrong location or duplicated it in more than one location.

How can it be determined for sure / is there even a way?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0 );
```

This will give you a sub domain and a domain its self.
e.g: sub.domain.com or domain.com/sub

i hope this will work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not but I think that under an actual environment it would, this is simply a limitation of running locally with MAMP. (I may be wrong though)